# Updating object variable in hashmap of the format Hashmap<String, List<Object>>

Tags: java

I am trying to simplify the code for updating or a certain object which is inside an arraylist as value.

I have to do something as follows:

```
CustomObject obj1 = new CustomObject.builder().var1("value1").var2(5).build();
Map<String, List<CustomObject>> customMap = populateMap();
customMap.add(Arrays.asList(obj1));
```

I have to update obj1 as (value1,10)

```
CustomObject obj1 = new CustomObject.builder().var1("value1").var2(5).build();
CustomObject obj2 = new CustomObject.builder().var1("value2").var2(4).build();
Map<String, List<CustomObject>> customMap = new HashMap<>();
customMap.add("key1", Arrays.asList(obj1, obj2));
List<CustomObject> tempList = customMap.get("key1");
tempList.get(0).setvar2(10);
customMap.put("key1",tempList);
```

Comment: The last line, `customMap.put("key1",tempList);`, is superfluous - this list is already in the map, you just used `get` to retrieve it from the map using the same key. It's the same list that's already there.

Comment: forgive the correctness of my code, My intent is to update the value of Obj1 and then again put that list as value to "key1".

Comment: That list is already the value for "key1". You don't need to put it in the hashmap because it's already there.

Comment: So I can just do tempList.get(0).setvar2(10); and it will update the value in my hashmap? 
Just to confirm : 
CustomMap.get("key1").get(0).getvar2(); will return 10?

Comment: Also, please note that customMap.get("key3") will return null